# SQL Query in Access with YesNo field Returns No Results

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am learning to use SQL in Access 2013 and things are going well, but I'm having some trouble with one of the objectives of the assignment. First of all, here is the table information that I need to consider:

```
Field Name          Data Type
StudentID           Short Text
FirstName           ""
MiddleInitial       ""
LastName            ""
DateofBirth         Date/Time
GradePointAverage   Number
Major               Short Text
CreditsEarned       Number
Probation           Yes/No
USCitizen           Yes/No
Class               Short Text
```

What I need to do is determine the students on Probation who are not US Citizens. Following is my SQL Query Code:

```
SELECT   StudentID, LastName, FirstName, Major, Probation, USCitizen 
FROM Student
WHERE    Probation = 1
AND      USCitizen = 0;
```

There is one record on the Student table that should show up as a result when I run this query, but the query is blank instead, showing the column names but with no rows of data. This is just one aspect of a larger assignment and while I'm not having any difficulty with the other objectives, this one is stumping me. Why is it not returning the one row result? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell without seeing the content of the row that should show up. Judging from the Where-Clauses, either `Probation` is not `1` or `USCitizen` is not `0` or both. Would it be possible for you to show us the data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: Well, it asks me for a Password and I don't see anywhere where I can sign up... so I'm afraid it doesn't help. :(

Comment: DONT put your password or user online!!\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Microsoft Access Data Types on W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp), can you try comparing to -1 rather than 1:

> A logical field can be displayed as Yes/No, True/False, or On/Off. In code, use the constants True and False (equivalent to -1 and 0). Note: Null values are not allowed in Yes/No fields.

Sorry, don't have a copy of access handy to try this out.

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot for the tip! Sorry about not being able to get a non https image up on my site for the data, to @waka .

Comment: Glad to hear it. The mind boggles a little that -1==yes==true.